# chakra-ui & css question: Show html text inside Popover

Tags: css, reactjs, chakra-ui, vanilla-extract

I want to show html text `<ul><li>test</li><li>test</li><li>test</li></ul>` inside popover when I hover "HOVER HERE".

This is what I want↓

- test
- test
- test

Here is my code

```
 <Popover placement="top-start" trigger="hover">
  <PopoverTrigger>
   <span>HOVER HERE</span>
  </PopoverTrigger>
  <PopoverContent backgroundColor="white" color="black">
  <PopoverBody>
   <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: "<ul><li>test</li><li>test</li><li>test</li></ul>" }} />
  </PopoverBody>
 </PopoverContent>
</Popover>
```

With the code above, I've got this

[image]

so I added css

```
<PopoverBody>
   <div className={textCss} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: "<ul><li>test</li><li>test</li><li>test</li></ul>" }} />
</PopoverBody>
```

```
import { style } from "@vanilla-extract/css";

export const textCss = style({
        display:"list-item",
        listStyleType:"disc", 
})
```

now I get this↓

[image]

list with only one bullet point..

Is there any way to display list item with bullet points, one on each line?

Comment: _"now I get this↓ list with only one bullet point.."_ - because you applied the style to the div. That div now _is_ your only "item" here.

Comment: right, I tried to apply the style to ul, but could not find the way using vanilla-extract. I solved the issue, by using css modules instead. @CBroe